# SEHException in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Setup:

- .Net-DLL written in C#
- C++/CLI Wrapper-Dll calling the .Net-DLL
- VS2013, Windows7 32Bit, .Net 4.5.2

Assigning a value larger than 2^31-1 to a double in the .Net-DLL will result in an SEHException, everything works fine with smaller values.

```
public void Foo()
{
    double foo = 2147483648d;
        ...
}
```

does throw an SEHexception when called from the C++/CLI, whereas

```
public void Foo()
{
    double foo = 2147483647d;
        ...
}
```

doesn't. Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid the exception?

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: You are probably running native code in a library that tinkers with the FPU control word and enables floating point exceptions.  That's poison to managed code.  Start debugging and use Debug > Windows > Registers.  Right-click, tick "Floating point".  The CTRL register value matters, it needs to be 0x027F.  When you step through your code and see it change then you found the troublemaker.  The Borland CRT is a common cause.  You can correct it with _control87() but you do get the decide whether you make the library or the C# code misbehave.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the errror.

Answer (score 1):

The DLLs were called from an application which changed the FPU control world. Setting

```
_control87(_CW_DEFAULT, MCW_EM);
```

in the C++/CLI Wrapper-DLL before calling into the managed DLL is a quick fix.